# php-fpm status shows listen queue 0 when it is delaying requests

Tags: linux, nginx, php, php-fpm, php7

I have a php-fpm server running on a high-traffic website (behind nginx). It is frequently reaching a point where the active processes are equal to the maximum number of processes, which is the most that the server's memory will allow.

When this happens it can take 5 - 10 seconds to load the php-fpm status page. It appears that the request is being queued. However the listen queue value always shows 0.

Why wouldn't this report the correct value?

Comment: Because the connection is being queued elsewhere?

Comment: Any possible ways to identify this, given that nginx is communicating with php-fpm over unix sockets?

Comment: Do some [custom logging](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) with the various [`$upstream_*_time`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_connect_time) variables.